# How do yo save an Excel file to a SharePoint Team Site Documents library?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I'm trying to save an Excel file to a SharePoint Team Site Documents and keep getting errors. Has anyone done this successfully and is willing to share how to do it please?

```vb
Sub Macro2()
    Dim UserName As String
    UserName = Environ("Username")

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _ 
"https://engineeringinspection.sharepoint.com/sites/Enginspire_SharedFolder/Shared%20Documents/UserName" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Note: I've not used `UserName` in above effort to save to simplify the Save action.

Comment: Lookup how to concatenate strings

Comment: "keep getting errors" - always helps your question to be *as specific as possible* about exactly what's happening when you run your code.  That doesn't look like an actual filename though ?  More like a path.